# Anonymous Classes - when are they created?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Does an anonymous class get created (not instantiated, but the class actually being defined/loaded) each time its enclosing method is called or are they reused? For instance:

```
public MyInterface getAnonymousMyInterface() {
 return new MyInterface(){
  public void doStuff(){
   System.out.println("did stuff");
  }
 }
}
```

Will calling `getAnonymousMyInterface()` create two different classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it will not. 
A single class is created at compile time for the anonymous class (in the form `OuterClass$1.class`) and that is so the single class that is loaded by the classloader.
Then at runtime, each `getAnonymousMyInterface()` invocation will create a distinct instance of the `MyInterface`  anonymous class as the `new` operator  creates a new instance of the class declared after that.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out by running the following program:

```
public class Main {
 public static interface MyInterface {
  void doStuff();
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(getAnonymousMyInterface().getClass().equals(getAnonymousMyInterface().getClass()));
 }


 public static MyInterface getAnonymousMyInterface() {
  return new MyInterface() {
   public void doStuff() {
    System.out.println("did stuff");
   }
  };
 }
```

This prints `true` so the answer is no, an anonymous class is created once, and each instance is from the same class.

Comment: You can also take a look at the output class files, the anonymous classes are usually named `Main$1.class`. It's proof that it's generated at compile time.